# Create database in WebSQL

Tags: javascript, web-sql

Been at this for hours and hours without end debugging why my `CREATE TABLE` statement failed.
Tested it within a `MySQL` database and it works just fine. But for some reason all my SELECT's can't get my login table like it doesn't exists(The error says).

Here is my `SQL` for creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login(
id SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
user_type SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
user_data text NOT NULL, 
created_on datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
);
```

I just cannot see where the error is. One other major issue is that after hours while googling i haven't found any solid wiki that provides enough information about the `API` for me to really use it. So i had to jump around from site to site to get bites of information.

Hope someone can help me sort out the issue with the `Query`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was about MySQL, as you mention it several times, but it looks like you're actually using WebSQL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sry for posting the issue. Already found what i done wrong.
Here is the solution for anyone else who might encounter the same thing.

I simply wrote "AUTO_INCREMENT" as in MySQL where i had to be "AUTOINCREMENT" without the _

Answer (score -1):

Just as a friendly note, the WebSQL Standard isn't recommended:  [Is it recommended to use the web sql database for storage on the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001657/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-web-sql-database-for-storage-on-the-client-side)

For a different Client-Side Relational Database Solution, try: [SequelSphere](http://www.sequelsphere.com)

It is an HTML5 Relational Database Engine that supports SQL and stores it's data in Local Persistence. It does not use WebSQL databases, but rather is its own SQL engine. As such, it will work in any JavaScript compliant browser. While it currently only supports Local Storage, very soon SequelSphere will support other local persistence engines such as IndexedDB and File API.

For full disclosure: I am related to the company SequelSphere. :)

Comment: Sounds interesting. Might give it a go on my next project :) But for now all i needed was to cache the response of a ajax call with the users basic information so that i can still show information for them even tho they are not connected to the internet. So kinda using the WebSQL for cache so that i don't beat the crap out of our servers with alot of requests.

Choosen WebSQL because of it's performance in this one. But i will differently check out that project. Thanks.